# Como Mantener la Selección de un DataGridView Solo en una Columna C# Visual Studio Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, checkbox, datagridview

Necesito que cuando de clic en una columna de mi DataGridView Solo se mantenga Selecciona un Header no importa en que parte de la tabla de clic.

Esto por que quiero Marcar y Desmarcar los CheckBox con la Barra de Espacio del Teclado, pero si no estoy posicionado en el Header que le pertenece al CheckBox no funciona Marcar con espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por eso quiero que cuando de clic en alguna parte de la tabla la Selección de Header se Mantenga en la del CheckBox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En resumen tu lo que quieres hacer es q al apretar la tecla espacio se active o desactive el checkbox de ese registro que tienes marcado_

Comment: Si. Eso quiero hacer. que ya lo hace por defecto, pero solo si esta posicionado en el Header del Checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el evento **KeyPress** del **DataGridView** pon esto:

```
if (e.KeyChar == 32)
{
   var fila = dgvColumnas.CurrentRow;
   var celdaCheckBox = fila.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

   if (Convert.ToBoolean(celdaCheckBox.Value))
   {
      celdaCheckBox.Value = false;
   }
   else
   {
      celdaCheckBox.Value = true;
   }
}
```

Aqui preguntamos si la tecla que se pulso es el espacio, y de serlo entonces obtendriamos la fila actual sobre la que estamos parados(esto es independiente de la celda). Al obtener la fila actual, obtendremos la celda 0 de esa fila que seria la celda que maneja el checkbox y posteriormente preguntamos si esa celda tiene el checkbox marcado o no. De tenerlo marcado, pues se desmarca, y de tenerlo desmarcado pues se marca.

Posteriormente iriamos al evento **CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged** del **DataGridView** y pondremos esto:

```
if (dgvColumnas.IsCurrentCellDirty)
{
   dgvColumnas.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Este codigo refresca el **DataGridView** en caso de que hayan cambios pendientes que no se hayan procesado en el grid.